# how to instantiate a java class from within JSNI

Tags: gwt, jsni

I'm trying to instantiate a java type inside a JSNI method body, using the JSO's package-private's `::new()` method, but all instances are returned as null handles.
how come?

Is it possible to instantiate the class using a similar syntax to Java?

Here is the relevant code:

```java
public class OnChangeHandlerJso extends JavaScriptObject {

    protected OnChangeHandlerJso() {};

    public static native JavaScriptObject create() /*-{

        return function(cm, changeInfo) {

            var eventBus = @com.gigaspaces.codemirror_gwt.client.events.EventUtils::CODE_MIRROR_EVENT_BUS;

            var event = @com.gigaspaces.codemirror_gwt.client.events.EditorContentChangeEvent::new()();

            // could something like this work?
            // var event = new @com.gigaspaces.codemirror_gwt.client.events.EditorContentChangeEvent;

            event.@com.gigaspaces.codemirror_gwt.client.events.EditorContentChangeEvent::setCm(Lcom/gigaspaces/codemirror_gwt/client/jsni/CodeMirrorJso;)(cm);
            event.@com.gigaspaces.codemirror_gwt.client.events.EditorContentChangeEvent::setChangeInfo(Lcom/gigaspaces/codemirror_gwt/client/jsni/ChangeInfoJso;)(changeInfo);
            eventBus.@com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventBus::fireEvent(Lcom/google/gwt/event/shared/GwtEvent;)(event);
        };
    }-*/;
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure, you are trying to create an instance of JavaScript Overlay Type from JSNI?

Comment: no, `EditorContentChangeEvent` is a pure java type - thus the question.

Comment: I recently tried to do the same type of thing.  I could create the event, but when trying to fire the event I couldn't ever match the fireEvent signature because it wants a GWTEvent<T> type that just didn't seem to match the signature of the Event even though it was of that type.  I ended up just putting the event creation in a gwt method and calling it that method from jsni.

Comment: finally, i did exactly the same (see the code in the answer). this, however, is not the same case, as when referring to typed arguments (generics) one could lose the type declaration altogether. this will work as the GWT compiler will allow it, and the compiled code is weakly typed - being native JS.  BTW - this is recommended by the GWT team.

Comment: solved by detaching Java API to Java methods, and using event delegation from JSNI to the Java layer. Code will soon be attached as an answer.

Comment: @EliranMalka, I Just came across the same issue. How did you solve it eventually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved like this:

#### The overlay type

```java
public class OnChangeHandlerJso extends JavaScriptObject {

    protected OnChangeHandlerJso() {};

    public static native OnChangeHandlerJso create() /*-{
        return function(cm, changeInfo) {
            @com.gigaspaces.codemirror_gwt.client.vo.OnChangeHandler::handle(Lcom/gigaspaces/codemirror_gwt/client/jsni/CodeMirrorJso;Lcom/gigaspaces/codemirror_gwt/client/jsni/ChangeInfoJso;)(cm, changeInfo);
        };
    }-*/;
}
```

#### The handler

```java
public class OnChangeHandler implements JsoWrapper<OnChangeHandlerJso> {

    public static void handle(CodeMirrorJso cmJso, ChangeInfoJso changeInfoJso) {
        // ...
        EventUtils.CODE_MIRROR_EVENT_BUS.fireEvent(new EditorContentChangeEvent(cm, changeInfo));
    }
}
```