# How to pass a value from JS code to Java in JSNI

Tags: gwt, jsni

I want to pass the acceleration's value from js to java. Could anyone told me where is wrong?

Here is my code:

```
public class Accelerometer extends JavaScriptObject {

protected Accelerometer(){};

public static native double getCurrentAccelerationX() /*-{
    var x = 0.0;
    $wnd.ondevicemotion = function(event){
    //$wnd.alert(event.accelerationIncludingGravity.x);
    x = event.accelerationIncludingGravity.y; 
    };
    return x;
}-*/;
```

}

Comment: see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584991/how-to-instantiate-a-java-class-from-within-jsni).

Answer (score 0):

OK, so what you have will not work because your function returns immediately, but the actual value is not available until a later time.

You need to make your JSNI function invoke a method in your class when it changes.

(In addition: if what you have posted is the extent of your Accelerometer class, there is no need to make it extend `JavaScriptObject`.)

Try something like this:

```
package foo.bar;

public class Accelerometer {
    public void currentAcceleration(double x, double y) {
        Window.alert("currentAcceleration: " + x + ", " + y);
    }

    public static native void getCurrentAcceleration(Accelerometer p) /*-{
        $wnd.ondevicemotion = function(event) {
            var acc = event.accelerationIncludingGravity;
            $entry( p.@foo.bar.Accelerometer::currentAcceleration(DD)(acc.x, acc.y) );
        };
    }-*/;
}
```

You could make this method a member of Accelerometer rather than a static, but I prefer to pass the instance as a parameter to the function to avoid any confusion with `this`.